# How to use more than one shader program?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glew, freeglut

Using one shader program my code looks something like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
InitFunctions();
glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);

//render objects

glutSwapBuffers();
```

But I wanted to add another shader program but it seems to clear the screen. Even just putting this after rendering the objects clears the screen:

```
glUseProgram(ShaderProgramNew);
```

The only time the screen it doesn't clear the screen is when I use the same shader in both uses of glUseProgram()

To load the shaders i use this function:

```
GLuint ShaderProgramManager::loadProgram(char* VertexShaderFileLocation, char*     FragmentShaderFileLocation){

cout << "Creating Shader...\n";
cout << "Initalizing Variables\n";
GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
GLuint VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

string VString = loadShader(VertexShaderFileLocation);
string FString = loadShader(FragmentShaderFileLocation);

const GLchar* VText = (const GLchar*)VString.c_str();
const GLchar* FText = (const GLchar*)FString.c_str();

cout << "Load VertexShader and FragmentShader\n";

const GLchar* pp[1];
pp[0] = FText;
GLint Lengthss[1];
Lengthss[0] = strlen(FText);
glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&pp, Lengthss);
glCompileShader(FragmentShader);

const GLchar* p[1];
p[0] = VText;
GLint Lengths[1];
Lengths[0] = strlen(VText);
glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&p, Lengths);
glCompileShader(VertexShader);

GLint success;
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success) {
    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, InfoLog);
}


glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success) {
    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", GL_VERTEX_SHADER, InfoLog);
}

cout << "Shaders Compiled.\n";



cout << "Attach Shaders\n";
glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);

cout << "Link Program\n";
glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);

cout << "Validate Program\n";
glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
cout << "Complete.\n";
return ShaderProgram;
```

}

And this:

```
string ShaderProgramManager::loadShader(char* location){

string textS = "";
string line;
ifstream myfile(location);

cout << "Start of shader tex:\n" << "\n";

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        //cout << line << "\n\n";
        textS = textS + line + "\n";
    }

    cout << "End of shader text" << "\n";

    //text = new char[sizeOfCharArray];
    //strcat(text, textS.c_str());
    myfile.close();

    cout << "Shader Finished Loading.\n";


    return  textS;
}
```

At the start of the program i run this

```
ShaderProgramManager spm;

    ShaderProgram = spm.loadProgram("data/Shaders/VertexShader.txt", "data/Shaders/FragmentShader.txt");

        gWorldLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "gWorld");
        rotmLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "rotm");
        PermLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "persm");
```

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the shader programs. The creation of the shaders. How Uniforms and attributes are configured etc..

Comment: I don't mind people down-voting but i would appreciate a reason why so I can fix the problem.

Comment: I didn't down vote but in your edit you uploaded a lot of generic code for compiling a program which is probably fine cause one of your shaders work. But no details about what is in ShaderProgramNew content and setup. 
My bet is that ShaderProgramNew is invalid or improperly used.

Comment: I don't think that ShaderProgramNew is invalid because if I put it in both of the glUseProgram() it works as expected

Comment: Actually your program creation code is missing glDetach and glDelete for the temporary Shader objects

Comment: If each shader program is fine on its own then you are not clearing / setting up the state correctly between drawing with each program.
The uniforms might be in a different location so you may be loading them in correctly. The attributes might be different etc..

Comment: Oops, i come from a Java background and haven't been using C++ for a long time.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If I render an object after switching the shader program it displays on the screen but objects rendered before switching the shader program are not there

Comment: No matter if your shader is good or bad, I can't think of a possible scenario where simply calling `glUseProgram()` with any kind of shader would clear previous rendering. There has to be something else going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solutions works perfectly for me, when I want to use 2 different shader during one render pass.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram01);

// Do Modelview and projection matrix stuff and uniforms

// Render objects with fstshaderProgram

glUseProgram(shaderProgram02);
// Do Modelview and projection matrix stuff and uniforms

// Render objects with 2nd shaderProgram

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Very important is that you have to reupload all the needed uniforms. For this approach I assume that you are loading the shaders correctly and that they are working without problems. 
Using glut you only call glutSwapBuffers() one per iteration.

Comment: You was right! I was uploading ALL my uniforms at the start of the render function instead of uploading only the ones for that shader program after calling `glUseProgram() `

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: Yes. It is working now.

Comment: While this might solve the OP's problem, the explanation is really not correct. You don't have to re-upload the uniforms every time after calling `glUseProgram()`. The only thing that matters is that you set the uniforms while the correct program is bound. After that, they persist for this program. Quote from specs: "Uniforms are program object-speciﬁc state. They retain their values once loaded, and their values are restored whenever a program object is used, as long as the program object has not been re-linked."